# vb doens't excute all batch commands, just a few

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

First I'm new at VB. So don't go hard on me :P

I want to run a batch file silently and after that a batch the normal way.
And this must run when the file is being opened so not via cmd.

I already tried something but it doesn't pause:

My *.vbs for the normal batch:

```
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute "C:\Apps\SV\Test.bat", 1, True
```

I don't have a .vbs for my silent batch(yet).

My Test.bat:

http://pastebin.com/u95WjzWF

The batch echo's a picture and then pause.
But when I run my VB script it shows for a sec and disappears.
I think VB didn't executed the pause command in the batch.

So what is the script to do this?

Comment: maybe using the k switch of cmd (cmd will stay active after execution of the command) ? `Shell.run("cmd.exe /k C:\Apps\SV\Test.bat", 1, True)`

Comment: What happens when you run your batch file directly from a command prompt? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @aphoria Yes when I run the batch from command promt it works fine or when I dubble clik on the batch it works fine too.

Comment: Your VBS and batch code work here just fine.  Double check the path to the batch file.

Comment: @Kayasax That just gave me a error: Can't use "" to call up sub-value. (Sorry for my bad english I got a dutch windows so I tried to translate it for you :) )

Comment: @foxidrive I know it works but the VBS script skips the pause command in my batch file. Thats is what needs to be fixed.

Comment: The pause works fine here - if the file displays for you then it has to execute the pause.  Put another pause in, without redirecting the output.  Maybe you have a typo in the code on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
In my batch the pause command is like this:

```
pause>swap
```

That doesn't work but when I do it like this:

```
pause >swap
```

Then it works and the batch pauses.

Thanks @Kayasax @aphoria @foxdrive